# Which tone of voice sounds better for a feedback feature?

Tags: copywriting, ux-writing, writing-direction

I'm designing a feedback feature that lets users give feedback on the website. This will be multistep.

I'm trying to decide what kind of tone of voice should the buttons follow, as the content in the feedback feature sounds more friendly and approachable.

for the 2 buttons what would be the better option from these. Any other suggestions are welcome.

1. 'Next' and 'finish'
2. 'i got more feedback' and 'I'm done'

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick reference about button usability - https://uxmovement.com/buttons/5-rules-for-choosing-the-right-words-on-button-labels/

"Next" and "Finish" are not strictly verbs.
"I got more feedback" and "I'm done" are not verbs either.

Some questions to consider before giving other options:

1. What does "Next" do? does it take the user to more feedback screens?
2. What does "Finish" do? does it send the feedback and end the feedback-giving process?

Assuming "Next" takes the user to more feedback screens, and "Finish" sends the rating and finishes the feedback process, an alternatives might be:

- "Write more feedback" and "Send rating"

Answer (score 2):

Rather than making this two steps:

1. Add star rating --> Click Next button --> 2. Leave comment --> Click Finish button

...you could use progressive disclosure here:

Add star rating --> optional comment box appears after stars are clicked --> user clicks button to submit both

If you go that route, "Send Feedback" would be a strong, decisive signal of what happens next.